# Is there a mapping for AG Grid ColumnState[] to GridState? [migration from v30 to v31]

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I want to leverage the new GridState API without having to transition the state at grid render time for users. Is there a clear mapping of ColumnState[], FilterModel, PivotMode, etc. to the new GridState object, so that I can transition the old state format to the new state format?